# wordpress//pods cms - how to specify a custom template file to my pod?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

First of all, I would like to say that I'm very sorry for this shamefull question !
On my wordpress (v3.5) I just downloaded and install pods cms plugin (2.2).

I made my new awesome pod object (News for example), I added few custom attributes and saved it. The permalink I used is /news/{name}

I enabled Pods Template and Pods page, and created few News in the wp dasboard.
Back to my frontend I have nothing when I try to reach mywordpress.com/news/MySuperNew
And more scary I digged and digged the web in order to know how to tell to podsCms that for each Pods News object, I would like to use a custom template file of my own name "mySuperTemplateForNews.php"

edit1 : I noticed that in the Pods Pages setup you can create pages and specify the template file (created in the current theme folder) you want to use. But I still have no clue on how to bind a specific pod to a specific template...

I hope someone will be able to help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permalinks enabled (anything but the default will work)?

You should make sure you add your pod page as "news/*"

Code goes into your pod page content area (or directly into your WP Page Template file) that contains the Pods [loop](http://pods.io/docs/find/) and your other code. If you're using Pod Page content to store your PHP, you'll need to put `pods_content()` into your WP Page Template file wherever you need it to be output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I have this detail page url in my pod page : news/{@permalink} I created a template named news.php in my the theme folder. I created a pod with this permalink "test123". When I try to reach this url /news/ I see what I put in my template file, but when I try to reach /news/test123 I have an error "Sorry, no posts matched your criteria." Do you have any idea ? Thank you very much!

Comment: The Pod's Detail URL should be news/{@permalink}/

Comment: The Pod Page's URI should be news/*